# kill background vs normal process in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I know how to kill a currently running foreground process, e.g.

$kill 15916

What I don't know is what is different about killing a background process.

What's different about killing a background process?

Answer (score 4):

*Nothing* is different about killing a background task. If you have the process id you can send it a signal (including a terminate or interrupt, as you're doing above)

I'm not sure about your definitions of foreground/background, though. Foreground is the process running in your shell, and your shell is waiting for it to finish before returning control to you. A background task is one that's been disconnected from the shell's input/output. Note that from the process' point of view, it doesn't *really* have a concept of foreground/background. That's really from the shell's point of view.

Comment: +1 for beginning the answer with *Nothing*. I would say though, that a lot of times background processes are killed with the `service` command and not `kill` or `killall`. But I'm sure signals are handled the same way, regardless.